# IPhone: different row selected

Tags: iphone, rows, multipleselection

When I select a row from a UITableView, that row and others below (several rows below the one selected) are also selected. Only the selected row is expected to be the selected one.

My code is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    //Deselect
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
} else {
    //Select
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to declare a new `NSMutableArray` (say `_selectedList`) of your datasource count. Populate it with NSNumber with value 0.

Declare `NSMutableArray *_selectedList;`  in .h file (as class member)

In `viewDidLoad` or `init` method,

```
_selectedList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( int i = 0; i < [datasource count]; i++ )
{
  [_selectedList addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
```

And make the following methods as follows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //...
    if (! [[_selectedList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue]) {
        //Deselected
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    } else {
        //Selected
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    //Deselect
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  } else {
    //Select
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
  }
  BOOL isSelected = ![[_selectedList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
  [_selectedList replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because the cells are re-used.
If you want to use the background color to show the selected state, you need to set it in the cell geter method

Adding this code should work :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //...
    if (!cell.selected) {
        //Deselected
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    } else {
        //Selected
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }

}
```

Comment: Some of the rows below the one selected (I have to scroll to see them) keep selected and, I scroll back to the selected, this one may not be selected but a near one is. This is strange. I will try making  in another way